# Bluetooth Connection between Python and Arduino, PyBlueZ

Tags: python, android, arduino, bluetooth

I am making a personal project that can make a connection between Python and Arduino via Bluetooth. I need the Python code  to connect to a HC-05 Bluetooth module and send characters to it. Code that I have made for the Arduino:

```cpp
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial bluetooth(10, 11);

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  bluetooth.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  if (bluetooth.available())
  {
    Serial.println(bluetooth.read());
  }
}
```

Code I have made so far for Python:

```py
import bluetooth

nearby_devices = bluetooth.discover_devices(lookup_names=True)
print("Found {} devices.".format(len(nearby_devices)))

for addr, name in nearby_devices:
    print("  {} - {}".format(addr, name))
```

Everytime I run this code, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\peiji\OneDrive\Documentos\Arduino\Carro\main.py", line 1, in 
    import bluetooth
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bluetooth'
```

I have already tried: `pip install pybluez`

However, I get this error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From Python version 3.9, Bluetooth connection using Serial Port Profile (SPP) has been possible with the standard Python install using the [socket](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html) library.

The HC-05 module is the server so you need to create a client. There is a blog comparing pyBluez and Python sockets here:
http://blog.kevindoran.co/bluetooth-programming-with-python-3/

The client example from Kevin's blog should do what you want if you update the address and port information:

```py
import socket

serverMACAddress = '00:1f:e1:dd:08:3d'  # Put your HC-05 address here
port = 1  # Match the setting on the HC-05 module
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_BLUETOOTH, socket.SOCK_STREAM, socket.BTPROTO_RFCOMM)
s.connect((serverMACAddress,port))
print("Connected. Type something...")
while 1:
    text = input()
    if text == "quit":
        break
    s.send(bytes(text, 'UTF-8'))
s.close()
```